# NodeJS: JSON Array - Parse/Decode from Array

Tags: node.js

I have a JSON Array with:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "user": "niebauer",
    "channels": [
        {
            "name": "maxmustermann",
            "followers": 17193,
            "views": 650255,
            "partnered": false
        },
        {
            "name": "harrypotter",
            "followers": 21487,
            "views": 5110,
            "partnered": false
        },
        {
            "name": "welten",
            "followers": 1017,
            "views": 9318,
            "partnered": false
        },
        {
            "name": "meeresbuecher",
            "followers": 5141,
            "views": 61411,
            "partnered": false
        },
        {
            "name": "weltrekord",
            "followers": 171777,
            "views": 17832138,
            "partnered": true
        },
        {
            "name": "tvtotaler",
            "followers": 2117,
            "views": 21300,
            "partnered": false
        },
        {
            "name": "kramkiste",
            "followers": 6819,
            "views": 30414,
            "partnered": false
        }
    ],
    "cursor": ""
}
```

And now i want to have in my output only the name from the channels. It should be:
maxmustermann
harrypotter
welten
...

How can I do this in Node.js? I found many questions with it, but no actual answer. Most of them are from 2012 and older. Thanks.

In this there are 7 channels. How can i get the counter aswell for it? So i get a output of "7"?

Comment: you can use map function before setting data to channel. But first you have to show the code where you want names and where you're getting channels, so please attach some code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
console.log(data.channels.map((channel) => channel.name)) 
// ["maxmustermann" ,"harrypotter", "welte",...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic and get counter also :

```js
let obj = {
  status: 200,
  user: "niebauer",
  channels: [
    {
      name: "maxmustermann",
      followers: 17193,
      views: 650255,
      partnered: false,
    },
    {
      name: "harrypotter",
      followers: 21487,
      views: 5110,
      partnered: false,
    },
    {
      name: "welten",
      followers: 1017,
      views: 9318,
      partnered: false,
    },
    {
      name: "meeresbuecher",
      followers: 5141,
      views: 61411,
      partnered: false,
    },
    {
      name: "weltrekord",
      followers: 171777,
      views: 17832138,
      partnered: true,
    },
    {
      name: "tvtotaler",
      followers: 2117,
      views: 21300,
      partnered: false,
    },
    {
      name: "kramkiste",
      followers: 6819,
      views: 30414,
      partnered: false,
    },
  ],
  cursor: "",
};

let result = obj.channels.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
    prev.name.push(curr.name);
    prev.count++;
    return prev;
  },
  { name: [], count: 0 }
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this with [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
const channelNames = data.channels.map((channel) => channel.name);
console.log(channelNames);
```

Or by looping through the items using [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method and then push each name into an array like this:

```js
const channelNames = [];
data.channels.forEach((channel) => {
  channelNames.push(channel.name);
});
console.log(channelNames);
```